# IFEXISTS=TRUE of h2 is not supposed in Java

Tags: java, h2

[image: The bug]
Here is the whole exception was thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unsupported connection setting " IFEXISTS" [90113-194]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.readSettingsFromURL(ConnectionInfo.java:269)
at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.<init>(ConnectionInfo.java:77)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at Driver.<init>(Driver.java:18)
at App.<init>(App.java:6)
at App.main(App.java:13)
```

I have followed exactly [the tutorial of H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists). But the result isn't coming out well. I only copied the code `IFEXISTS=TRUE`, not retyping, so there is no way it could be typo. Am I doing wrong something?

Comment: Try removing the space before `IFEXISTS`.

Comment: Please forgive my stupid. And thanks btw, it works miracle... don't know where to hide my face anymore.